# Async-reading network stream hangs in proxy for SignalR upgrade request

Tags: .net, async-await, stream

I'm writing a small proxy to be used for in-house development purposes, based off of this project: https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy

It works fine except for SignalR scenarios. The problem is when the client sends the SignalR upgrade request, and the proxy is trying to copy the SignalR HUB response content, it never returns:

```cs
var contentStream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
// never returns:
await contentStream.CopyToAsync(proxyResponse.Body, StreamCopyBufferSize, context.RequestAborted);
```

I have traced the problem into the ASP.NET Core code and it seems to be related to the async nature of the operation, so maybe a deadlock? Any type of reading that network stream produces the same result (not just `CopyToAsync`). Please note I strictly use async/await. I *never* use `Task.Result` anywhere (I learned that lesson many years ago).

How can I troubleshoot this scenario?

Comment: Couldn't the problem be that HTTP protocol is request/response, but SignalR is upgrading from HTTP to WebSockets that is bi-directional communication on a open channel? Couldn't the proxy HTTP client upgrade the connection instead of passing it to client? I would say in case of upgrade you want to also change how the proxy deal with such a scenarios.

Comment: I do get a response from the upgrade request though. It's just when I async read the content this happens

Comment: Just an idea. Can you try to use `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` (`http.GetAync("localhost/path", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);`) as by default `HttpClient` is set to wait until entire body is read which might never happen.

Comment: I already do that:
`proxyService.Client.SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.RequestAborted);`

Comment: If it's a bidirectional channel you need to make sure to push the writes also.

Comment: The traffic hangs in the second, 'Upgrade', handshake (to web sockets) POST. So normal POST roundtrip when it hangs. The bi-directional traffic has not yet commenced